# How can a custom column in one PowerQuery reference another PowerQuery

Tags: excel, powerquery, excel-2016

I want to use data from one power query in the creation of a custom column in a second power query, but not sure how to do it (or if I'm going about this the wrong way).

I have one query (QueryOne) that ends up returning an integer column (DataValue) and a datetime column (DateOfCompletion).  I then have a second query (QueryTwo) that have a PeriodName, StartDate, and EndDate.  What I'm after, is on the second query to have a calculated column that is the sum of QueryOne.DataValue where QueryOne.DateOfCompletion is between QueryTwo.StartDate and QueryTwo.EndDate.  (so I get the DataValue of items completed by the PeriodName)

I cannot seem to make reference to QueryOne when creating the custom column on QueryTwo; is this possible or is there a standard method of combining data of that form?

Answer (score 3):

Here's *one* way...

If I start with this as QueryOne:

[image]

And this as QueryTwo:

[image]

I can get this result with the code below:

[image]

Here's the M code:

```
let
Source = QueryTwoSource,
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "QueryOne", each QueryOne),
#"Expanded QueryOne" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "QueryOne", {"DateValue", "DateOfCompletion"}, {"QueryOne.DateValue", "QueryOne.DateOfCompletion"}),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded QueryOne", "Custom", each if ([QueryOne.DateOfCompletion] >= [StartDate]) and ([QueryOne.DateOfCompletion] <= [EndDate]) then "True" else "False"),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Added Custom1",{{"Custom", "WithinPeriod"}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Renamed Columns", {"PeriodName", "WithinPeriod"}, {{"CountWithinPeriod", each Table.RowCount(_), type number}, {"SumOfDateValuesWithinPeriod", each List.Sum([QueryOne.DateValue]), type number}, {"AllData", each _, type table}}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Grouped Rows", each ([WithinPeriod] = "True")),
#"Expanded AllData" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "AllData", {"QueryOne.DateValue", "QueryOne.DateOfCompletion"}, {"QueryOne.DateValue", "QueryOne.DateOfCompletion"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded AllData",{"WithinPeriod"})
in
#"Removed Columns"
```

*p.s. The `Source` in the code above is just another query of a spreadsheet table that has the three columns: PeriodName, StartDate, and EndDate. ...Similar to how QueryOne is a query of a spreadsheet table with DateValue and DateOfCompletion columns. So, basically, `Source = QueryTwoSource` is how I got QueryTwo, pictured above. I could have directly used the spreadsheet table as QueryTwo's source instead, but this is how I did it.*

Answer (score 0):

Do both tables have the same number of rows? If you add an index column you can reference the row of `QueryOne` and then reference the column. For example, if your index column is called `Index`, then `QueryOne{Index}[DataValue]` will access the value in the `DataValue` column at that row.

In general, you can use the query's name to access its value in the custom column formula. `QueryOne` will give you the table from QueryOne. If your query has spaces or other special characters in its name, like in `Query One`, then `#"Query One"` will get its value.